# Speeding up code: reducing 'user' time

Tags: r, performance, rcpp

I have a function that I will be calling heavily (roughly 10^11 times per iteration in an optimisation, for a few different experiments). I have implemented a fast version, but I am struggling to see how I can improve performance. The 'system' time is minimal, and the user time is high.

Here's the code, it takes in an integer and returns a vector that represents that integer is a different base counting system (eg base = 2 gives binary, base = 10 gives the standard result back). The parameter k gives the length of the vector to return, so there may be many zeros at the front.

As you'll see, the functions take 5 or 7 seconds to run, but none of it is system time. I would like to understand why, and if there are ways to speed it up. I have this same problem with other functions (99% of the time is spend in one function in a loop, but speeding it up 200fold only halved the run-time), but am showing this one for clarity.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

# Rcpp version of the function
cppFunction('
NumericVector convert10tobase_c(double number_b10, int k, int base = 4){
    if(number_b10 >= pow(base, k)){
        stop("k is not large enough to contain the number in this base");
    }
    NumericVector ret(k);
    if(k == 1){
        return number_b10;
    }
    for (int i = 1 ;i < k; i++){
        double entry = floor(number_b10 / pow(base, (k - i)));
        ret[i-1] = entry;
        number_b10 = number_b10 - entry * pow(base, (k - i));
    }
    ret[k-1] = number_b10;
    return ret;
}')

# R version of the function
convert10tobase <- function(number_b10, k, base = 5){
    if(number_b10 >= base ^ k){
        stop("k is not large enough to contain the number in this base")
    }
    ret <- rep(0, k)
    if(k == 1){
        return(number_b10)
    }
    for (i in 1:(k - 1)){
        entry <- floor(number_b10 / base^(k-i))
        ret[i] <- entry
        number_b10 <- number_b10 - entry * (base ^ (k - i))
    }
    ret[k] <- number_b10
    return(ret)
}

# generate test data one hundred, thousand and million integers
set.seed(1)
base <- 4
k <- 8
ints_short <- floor(runif(1e2) * (base^k))
ints_long <- floor(runif(1e4) * (base^k))
ints_v_long <- floor(runif(1e6) * (base^k))

# benchmark the Rcpp version
microbenchmark(
    one = convert10tobase_c(ints_short[1], k, base),
    hundred = sapply(1:length(ints_short), function(i) convert10tobase_c(ints_short[i], k, base)),
    ten_thous = sapply(1:length(ints_long), function(i) convert10tobase_c(ints_long[i], k, base)),
    times = 100)

# test R and Rcpp times
r_start <- proc.time()
t <- sapply(1:length(ints_v_long), function(i) convert10tobase(ints_v_long[i], k, base))
r_stop <- proc.time()

c_start <- proc.time()
t <- sapply(1:length(ints_v_long), function(i) convert10tobase_c(ints_v_long[i], k, base))
c_stop <- proc.time()

# results - little time in 'system'
r_stop - r_start
c_stop - c_start
```

As an aside, I included a comparison of calling the function once, a hundred times and a hundred thousand times. The time for one hundred calls was 300 times slower than for one, while for ten thousand calls was thirty times slower than one hundred calls. I would like to understand why, and would appreciate any resources that could explain it.

Thanks!

Comment: You might benefit from vectorizing your function, instead of calling it separately for each integer you want to check.

Comment: There is a small potential benefit from reusing the `pow` value instead of computing it twice. Also notice that the number of exponentiations can be reduced by noting the "divide by `base`" relationship between `i` and `i + 1`.

Comment: Much of the time is spent with the overhead of calling a function. You can achieve a dramatic performance improvement if you substitute `sapply` with a C++ loop, i.e., vectorize the function as pointed out by @Heroka.

Comment: Would it be a problem if numbers that are too large are returned as NA?

Comment: @Heroka I've implemented your suggestion and it is indeed the repeated function call slowing it down. Thanks for the observation, this will help me greatly.

Comment: @Roland thanks for explaining the source of the poor performance, the C++ loop is almost 100 times faster.

Comment: @Heroka NA wouldn't be a problem in principle, but it is more a sanity check to make sure that the other parameters have not been ignored. This output is used elsewhere, so I want to flag problems.

Comment: If you write the comment (with Roland's explanation) as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R is very good at efficiently doing the same thing to multiple similar things. Therefore, your code gets more efficient if you group similar things together before doing something. This can be a bit tricky to start with, especially when you've arrived from another coding background.

Here is a solution where your function is vectorized within R (unsure how this relates to C++ loop, probably something internal). It can probably be optimized further, but it's 100x faster than using `sapply` for each individual number. It returns a matrix with one row per number fed to it, and a column for each entry. When a number is larger than `base ^k`, a row of NA's is returned. In further work with the output, this row can then easily be identified.

```
convert10tobase_v <- function(number_b10, k, base = 5){
  orig_b10 <- number_b10 #save original for check after
  if(k == 1){
    return(number_b10)
  }
  #initialize matrix to store results
  ret <- matrix(0, ncol=k, nrow=length(number_b10))
  #tiny-forloop, won't influenc performance and makes
  #storing results/modifying number_b10 easier
  for (i in 1:(k - 1)){
    entry <- floor(number_b10 / base^(k-i))
    ret[,i] <- entry
    number_b10 <- number_b10 - entry * (base ^ (k - i))
  }
  ret[,k] <- number_b10
  ret[orig_b10 >= base ^ k,] <- NA #set 'too large' numbers to missing
  return(ret)
}
```

Microbenchmark:

```
Unit: microseconds
              expr        min          lq         mean     median          uq        max neval cld
        one_single     20.216     25.1910     31.94323     29.079     37.6310     58.469   100 a  
   hundred_singles   2217.461   2317.9145   2499.23338   2386.336   2498.4525   4436.476   100  b 
 ten_thous_singles 240467.874 246613.1635 253205.12598 249890.060 252432.2090 307050.155   100   c
             one_v     22.703     26.5910     33.09706     30.323     36.3875     62.823   100 a  
         hundred_v     53.181     56.9135     68.05703     61.889     75.5740    129.066   100 a  
       ten_thous_v   2641.359   2707.2920   2806.83843   2744.613   2827.9620   4645.160   100  b
```

Comment: Vectorization is a C-level `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the full example, this plus your and @Roland's comments have been a great help.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the nice question with data, code and a clear problem statement.